# Datos entre vistas con ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hola necesito pasar un dato de una vista a otra, pero no lo consigo.Alguien por favor me pdoría decir la forma más propia de mandar datos. En este caso mi dato lo estoy obteniendo de otra función y necesito saber cómo pasarlo es un **int** que ocupo como id

Esta es la vista de cual quiero mandar mis datos

```html
//vista index
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

   @Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Request", new { id = 123 })
```

Necesito que pasé por este controllador y me devuelva en la vista **Details**

```js
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.Id = id;
        return View();
    }
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detalles - Cotización";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

   <h1> Tu Id es: @ViewBag.Id </h1>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: así es @Xique pero me manda ese error u.u

Comment: no disucilpen, ahí puse un string, puedo poner un entero y obtengo el mismo error, si se dan cuenta el error dice que no le estoy pasando NADA D: , si recibiese el String me diría  "oye.... esto no vale..." ... pero pues no...

Comment: No amigo @Xique te aseguro que ese no es el error y alo probé con un int ... y me da exacto lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que te esta faltando son los atributos para el html en este caso seria null
te quedaria asi ->

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Compra", new { id = 123 },null)
```

y ya con eso puedes enviar el parámetro int como lo tienes 
o si quieres agregar los atributos pues lo pones asi :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Compra", new { id = 123 },new {@class="btn btn-primary" })
```

Comment: Me caso, gracias :3

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es no confundir la información temporal que pasa entre peticiones, si vas a usar `ViewBag` deberás usarlo tanto en el View como en el Controller, no es la mejor práctica usar `TempData` y `ViewBag`.

Para el paso de parámetros lo correcto sería enviarlos como parte del cuarto parámetro que es de tipo `IDictionary<string, object>`, por ejemplo:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Request", new { id = 123 })
```

Lo cual, el Controller recibirá ese dato como parámetro en el método y a su vez, lo guardamos en el diccionario temporal `ViewBag` para poder enviarlo a la vista `Details`:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = id;
    return View();
}
```

En la vista `Details`, lo podrás leer de igual forma haciendo uso del `ViewBag`, es decir, a modo de ejemplo si lo quisieras usar dentro de un elemento Html:

```
<h1> Tu Id es: @ViewBag.Id </h1>
```

Comment: obtuve esto como error 'The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'PCotiza_compras.Controllers.RequestController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters'

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim Eso significa que estás enviando un valor nulo al Controller, revisa qué información envías en el parámetro `Id` ;)

Comment: yo sé pero pues la estoy mandando como dijiste .. así '@Html.ActionLink("Check Request", "Details", "Request", new { id = 123 })' prove cambiando id = 123 por id = "123" aunque eso debería hacerlo string no?? como sea no salió D:

Comment: Es correcto, eso enviaría un string. Pregunta, ¿en el Controller de igual forma definiste el parámetro con el mismo nombre?

Comment: Listo lo he cambiado a como lo tengo para que veas que estoy haciendo